# Redirect users from www to non www URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to make a redirection in order to redirect all users who access `http://www.example.com` to `http://example.com`. I am using DigitalOcean (Ubuntu 14.10 x64).

First I created a `CNAME` record in my DigitalOcean DNS management:

```
- (Enter name) www
- (Enter hostname) @
```

Secondly, I placed the following code in my `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes
# Redirect www urls to non-www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. I can access `http://www.example.com` and `http://example.com` but I won't get redirected when accessing `http://www.example.com`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I tried it and I got no 500 error. How can I enable it?

Comment: In your Apache config find the `<Directory>` block for your `DocumentRoot` and change `AllowOverride` line to `AllowOverride All`. Restart Apache then.

Comment: Make sure `mod_rewrite` is installed too.

Comment: why don't you do it in PHP? `header('Location: '.$newURL);`

Answer (score 1):

Little bit off topic, but as alternative solution you can do it with PHP; something like this:

```
if (SUBSTR($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) === 'www.') {
    header('Location: http'.(ISSET($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on' ? 's':'').'://' . SUBSTR($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 4).$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I solved it with changing my Apache config.